# How to use array so i will get value either x[0] or x[1]

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I have many classes in css named like .show-1-2,show-2-3,show-3-2 and so on

```
var w , h;
x = [1,2,3];
y = [1,2,3] ; 
var nam = document.querySelector('show-' + x[0] + '-' + y[2]);  //show-1-3 is class name in css
```

how to pass array so i will get all either x[0] or x[1] or x[2] so it would be catch the class  .show-1-2,show-2-3,show-3-2.

Comment: What is purpose of creating two arrays which contain the  same elements? You can use a single array to achieve expected result.

Comment: You are missing `.` before `show-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a list of all the options and then query by the values in that list.

Note that to query classes you need them to have `.`:

```js
var w , h;
x = [1,2,3];
y = [1,2,3] ; 
all_classes = []
x.forEach(function(x_v) {
  y.forEach(function (y_v) {
    all_classes.push('.show-'+x_v+'-'+y_v)
  })
})
console.log(all_classes.join(","))
var nam = document.querySelector(all_classes.join(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply with `.show` in query selector. Because Its class .so mention with `.`

```js
var w , h;
x = [1,2,3];
y = [1,2,3] ; 
var nam = document.querySelector('.show-' + x[0] + '-' + y[2]);  
console.log(nam.innerHTML);
console.log('.show-' + x[0] + '-' + y[2])
```

```html
<div class="show-1-3">hello</div>
```